What is meta that comes with a tRPC response?
I'm making a tRPC call that returns a lot of data with dates, and in the response I get:
json: {} // the actual thing I requested
meta: {} // why do I need this?

Meta will be an extremely big object (~10mb), full of things like:
0.createdAt: ['Date']
0.posts.0.createdAt: ['Date']
0.posts.0.releasedAt: ['Date']
0.posts.0.foo.0.createdAt: ['Date']
0.posts.0.foo.0.bar.0.createdAt: ['Date']
0.posts.0.foo.0.bar.0.updatedAt: ['Date']
0.posts.0.foo.0.bar.1.createdAt: ['Date']
0.posts.0.foo.0.bar.1.updatedAt: ['Date']
0.posts.0.foo.0.bar.2.createdAt: ['Date']
0.posts.0.foo.0.bar.2.updatedAt: ['Date']

Is there a way to remove meta: from the response?

It comes from superjson, not trpc. You can use trpc without data transformers
